# 'Evaluate' meaning in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud

Can anyone explain 'evaluate' meaning in salesforce?
I saw 'evaluate' , using in Marketing Cloud journey builder data extension to choose *Evaluating New Records Only or Evaluating All Records.*
How can I understand 'evaluate' in salesforce?
Does it has smiliar word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluate in [this context](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_manage_audience_data.htm&language=en_US&type=5) means „process”.

**Evaluate new records only**:

This method processes only new contacts added since the last time it was run. It is useful when new rows are added to the data extension without deleting or changing old rows, like when an automation with an import activity appends records. This option usually makes the processing faster and more efficient.

**Evaluate all records**:

This method processes all contacts in the data extension every time it runs, according to the entry source's schedule. Use this option when the data extension is updated frequently. This option usually makes the processing slower.

---

In simpler terms, you can choose to process only new contacts or process all contacts in your data extension for journey entry, depending on how your data is updated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So when I see 'evaluate' in Salesforce it means 'process'?
'Provides attributes in the state they are in when evaluation occurs after the entry event has fired' > In this text, it means also process?

Comment: Well, evaluation means the act of examining or assessing something, but in the context of Journey Builder entry source it could be translated as processing and choosing which contacts should enter the journey. So the above sentence means that the attributes will not change after the processing of the entry event has started.